# I have a problem with a looping through an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am reading a string from a database that is composed of commas separated items,eg

```
3.99,10 weeks,300
```

That is not the problem. So I explode this:

```
$fn = array(explode(",",$im->features));
```

to get the individual items for the array.
But when I loop through it

```
@foreach($fn as $fun)
    {{$fun}}<br>
@endforeach
```

(The {{}} and @ are because this is Laravel) I get the following error:

> htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

Any help gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. Silly mistake. I put

```
$fn = array(explode(",",$im->features));
```

instead of

```
$fn = explode(",",$im->features);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$fn = explode(",", $im->features);

@foreach($fn as $fun)
    {{ $fun }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Note that if you want to display specific parts of each item, you will need to explode each individual item again (not sure if you need this). But you can achieve it as follows:

```
$fn = explode(",", $im->features);

$fnArray = [];
foreach ($fn as $item) {
    $itemParts = explode(",", $item);
    $fnArray[] = [
        'part1' => $itemParts[0],
        'part2' => $itemParts[1],
        'part3' => $itemParts[2]
    ];
}
```

Comment: I tried that and got "htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given"

Answer (score 0):

I think in $im->features are some html entities, so you can do this.

```
$fn = explode(",",$im->features);
@foreach($fn as $fun)
     {!! $fun !!}<br>
@endforeach
```